# AngularJS - Some beginner questions on performance and scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have recently inherited an angular module written by a third party developer. I have never worked with angular before and have been asked to make some fairly basic changes, but I am struggling with a couple of issues (I promise there is a question at the end of this).

In essence the module is just a multiple choice questionnaire, with a sequence of buttons and you click one to select an answer, and a forward / back button to move between questions.

At the moment the module is hard coded to use 5 buttons, and the position of the buttons is set in the controller as so:

```
// scope here is the scope for the main controller
$scope.answerOptions = [
    { pos: 70 },
    { pos: 215 },
    { pos: 360 },
    { pos: 505 },
    { pos: 650 }
];
```

The pos is simply the left offset and the vertical position is fixed. this is implemented on the template like so:

```
<div class="circle" ng-repeat="o in answerOptions"
    option-pos="{{o.pos}}"
    ng-hide="sectionEnd"
    ng-class="selectedOptionStyle($parent.selectedAnswer - 1 == $index)"
    ng-click="selectAnswer($index)">
</div>
```

And the directive `optionPos` is then:

```
.directive('optionPos', function(){
  return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('optionPos', function(x){
      elm.css('left', x - 60 + 'px');
    })
  }
})
```

I have been asked to make it work with arbitrary number of buttons and positioning in both x and y, and to allow customisable answers (at the moment it just sends the array index of the clicked button back to the server). I thought this would be an easy change, and admittedly it would be easy enough if I implemented the same system, setting the x and y using interpolation, then just adding Y to the optionPos directive. However I have a couple of problems with this approach:

- it doesn't scale well for the number of attributes on a button. e.g. as well as x and y there is some other data I would like to assign to the button from the answerOption object (such as the answer to send to the server, and potentially other things in the future), and I don't want to have to assign each one as a separate attribute on the DOM element.
- I am concerned that `attrs.$observe` is unnecessarily resource intensive since the value will never change once the module loads and $observe will (presumably?) add a watch to that property. Similarly for using interpolation to set the coordinates on the DOM element.
- In some indefinable way it feels wrong, like there is probably a better way to do this, I'm just not asking Google the right questions.

What I attempted to do, after much reading of Angular's docs and tutorials is something like this:

```
// this would no longer be hard coded into the controller
// but once it is retrieved, this is what is set in the scope
// scope is still the main controller scope
$scope.answerOptions = [
    { Answer: 1, pos: { X: 180, Y: 120} },
    { Answer: 2, pos: { X: 360, Y: 120} },
    { Answer: 3, pos: { X: 540, Y: 120} }
];
```

template:

```
<div class="circle" ng-repeat="o in answerOptions"
    answer-option="o"
    option-button
    ng-hide="sectionEnd"
    ng-class="selectedOptionStyle($parent.selectedAnswer - 1 == $index)"
    ng-click="selectAnswer(o.Answer)">
</div>
```

directive:

```
.directive('optionButton', function(){
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         scope: {
             answerOption: '='
         },
         link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
             elm.css('left', scope.answerOption.pos.X - 60 + 'px');
             elm.css('top', scope.answerOption.pos.Y - 60 + 'px');
         }
     }
```

The problem with the solution above is my directive is creating an isolated scope, so all the other directives with function calls to the scope such as the `ng-hide` are now broken, and I don't want to have to re-architect the whole module for what is essentially a very simple change

And so, as promised after my long rambling - the question:

To anyone with more than my 24 hours of experience with angular, am I going about this wrong way? The problems I have experienced which have gotten me to this point feel like a code smell, but I'm not sure if its because the original developer wrote the module in a way that is hard to maintain/extend, or if I'm taking completely the wrong approach. The problems I have been experiencing seem to stem from the fact that essentially the entire application logic is set up as various functions on the scope of the main controller. It takes about 800 lines of JS to set up the scope for that controller, with many functions defining a whole host of different things. Is this the way an angular application should be built, with most of the logic on the scope, then calling it directly from the template, e.g. `ng-hide="sectionEnd"`?

Comment: 800 lines of JS for controller setup code is _not_ normal. My totally non-expert opinion, dig into the docs for a couple more days and you'll rewrite this in a couple of hours to be what you need and more. Other than that it is hard to judge on your approach without detailed requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One monster controller is not good practice.  Each controller on a page should be focused, and should have at most have 5 methods (guideline).   By having focused controllers, you are managing how you get your application gets its data.

Once you have controllers to retrieve your application data, you should leverage directives to encapsulate functionality into reusable directives.

Also, $observe will not incur significant cost if the attribute and its interpolated value never changes.

I recommend the following guidelines:

1. Implement services to retrieve application data
2. Controllers should call services to retrieve application data and attach it to scope.
3. Directives should help keep your controller's thin, and improve maintainability by keeping complex or shared logic in re-usable directives.

Comment: Re 3, I see directives as a way to encapsulate presentation logic. They should help keep your controllers thin but this is not their specific purpose.

Comment: Yes, it is a side-effect, but it speaks to maintainability - which is a valid point

Comment: @DrewR That confirms what I have seen from other sites. This [tutorial on services, controllers and directives](http://kirkbushell.me/when-to-use-directives-controllers-or-services-in-angular) made a similar point (and was very helpful to me if anyone else comes across this via google and would like a beginners guide on when to use services, controllers and directives)